# Xcode send variable with url to php page, retrieve variable in php code for the select statement

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c

I am trying to call a php page that connects to mysql database. I have been successful in loading all data from the table to an UITableView in xcode.

What I need to do now is change the select statement to load the data from the table with specific ID.

Here is my xcode:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server/phppage.php"]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// here is where the variable i want to send 
    [postDict setValue:@"1" forKey:@"CategoryType"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *urlString =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"jsonRequest=%@", urlString];
    NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (!theConnection) {
        NSMutableData *responseData = nil;
        NSLog(@"connection failes");
    }
```

and here is the php page:-

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("","","database","") or die ( mysqli_error($MySQL_Handle) );
$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';
mysqli_query($con,$sSQL) or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase');

// this is where the variable sent from the xcode is received

$cid = $GET_["CategotyType"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM itesttable where phone = $cid";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
  $resultArray = array();
  $tempArray = array();
  while($row = $result->fetch_object())
  {
  $tempArray = $row;
     array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
  }
  echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I don't know if the error is in the xcode and I'm sending the variable `CategoryType` the wrong way, or it is in the php and I'm retrieving the variable in a wrong way ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `phone` is an INTEGER column? Because you can access to it without '' only if it is. If it is a VARCHAR, you have to change it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM testable WHERE phone = '".$cid."'";
```

However is a GET method, why don't you access it by URL?

```
http://wwww.yourdomain.ext/phpPage.php?CategoryType=YOUR_VALUE
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked ...
and i will check the access by url method, i never heard of it...

Comment: I am trying the following code to pass the categoryID value to the php page ....     NSString *CategoryID = @"2";
    NSString *strURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://jmobilesoft.com/super/iCategoryItems.php?CategoryID=%@",CategoryID];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];      however i keep getting back the items with categoryID=0 only !!!

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code you have a typo: you query the value for `CategotyType` instead of `CategoryType`.

Also, you really, *really* want to read about what a *SQL injection vulnerability* is and how to prevent them in PHP.

Comment: thanks for the correction, and seems that SQL injection vulnerability is something that i really needed to be aware of, thanks for bringing my attention to it.